# Introducir palabras con espacios en juego del ahorcado

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo problemas a la hora de que se pinten los guiones de la palabra si es una palabra con espacio. Por ejemplo: si es *"iron man"*, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se pinte así: _ _ _ _ - _ _ _?

```
 ´/**
  * FUNCION QUE REEMPLAZA EL TITULO POR TANTOS GUIONES COMO CARACTERES TENGA
  * @param {*} titulo NOMBRE DEL TITULO
  * @returns 
  */
 function reemplazaPalabraPorGuiones(titulo){
   let tituloGuiones =titulo.replace(/./g, "_ ");
   console.log(tituloGuiones);
   return tituloGuiones;

  }´
```

Comment: No veo que hayas intentado hacerlo... lo primero que se debe hacer antes de preguntar es investigar e intentar hacerlo tú mismo. Obviamente si le pides que reemplace absolutamente todo por guiones bajos, no vas a poder mantener los espacios ni nada... empieza haciendo que reemplace los espacios por guiones y luego en vez de usar `/./g` puedes usar algo como `/\w/g`, que hace match en cualquier LETRA (a-zA-Z), no en cualquier cosa (`.` en regex significa UN CARACTER, cualquiera! Incluso los espacios y los guiones!). Por cierto... no me gusta que me griten,  y título todo en mayúsculas está mal.

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como te mencionan en los comentarios, tendrías que usar la expresión regular `/\w/g` para que haga match a cualquier letra del abecedario y no los espacios ni otros caracteres. Si quieres un guion entre los espacios, puedes hacer `replace` nuevamente para que reemplace los espacios por un guion, sería algo así:

```js
function reemplazaPalabraPorGuiones(titulo) {
  let tituloGuiones = titulo.replace(" ", "- ").replace(/\w/g, '_ ');
  return tituloGuiones;
}

console.log(reemplazaPalabraPorGuiones("iron man"));
console.log(reemplazaPalabraPorGuiones("capitan america"));
console.log(reemplazaPalabraPorGuiones("thor"));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio de gran ayuda

Comment: @informaticoDudas recuerda verificar la respuesta si te sirvió para que tu pregunta esté como respondida, saludos =).

Answer (score 1):

Yo soy pésimo con expresiones regulares, así que te ofrezco una alternativa sin ellas:

```js
function GetMask(oracion){
  let mask=[];
  for(let l of oracion){
    if(l === " "){
      mask.push("-");
    }
    else{
      mask.push("_");
    }
  }
  return mask.join("");
}

console.log(GetMask("iron man"));
```

Básicamente recorremos la oración y reemplazamos espacio por guion y cualquier otro carácter por _

Comment: Si me vale tambien, pero tengo el juego ya en 300 lineas, y me falta hacer el ahorcado entre dos jugadores que no tengo ni idea del planteamiento xD, muchas gracias por la respuesta